# How to compare and remove values from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have nested dictionary with user input data:

```
{
    name: {key_to_compare: value, key_to_compare: value},
    name: {key_to_compare: value, key_to_compare: value},
    name :{key_to_compare: value, key_to_compare: value},
    ...
```

Number of name-key as well nested `{key_to_compare: value}` might vary. Then as input a get two `name_key`

The task is to compare the values of the same `key_to_compare` under different `name-key` and the `key_to_compare` with lower value to be removed. At the end the dictionary should keep the same format.
This is what I have tried:

```
first_player, second_player = split_line
player_to_remove[first_player] = []
player_to_remove[second_player] = []
if first_player in players_data.keys() and second_player in players_data.keys():
    for fp_keys, fp_value in players_data[first_player].items():
        for sp_keys, sp_value in players_data[second_player].items():
            if fp_keys == sp_keys:
                if fp_value > sp_value:
                    player_to_remove[second_player].append(sp_keys)
                    break
                elif fp_value < sp_value:
                    player_to_remove[first_player].append(fp_keys)
                    break
                elif fp_value == sp_value:
                    break
    if player_to_remove:
        for key, value in player_to_remove.items():
            for skill, points in players_data[key].items():
                if skill in value:
                    players_data[key].pop(skill)
```

This is part of the a the code that handle it. I try to loop the `name_key` and compare the `key_to_compare` values. The problems is that I can't modify the dictionary during the loops.
I tried to collect the `key_to_compare` in a separate dict with name as a key and a list of `key_to_compare` as values and then comparing to dictionaries to remove the matching `key_to_compare` for corresponding `key_names`.
I can't figure it out how to do it and may be there is some different approach in the first place.
This example of the dictionary:
**{'Peter': {'Adc': 400}, 'Bush': {'Tank': 150}, 'Frank': {'Mid': 200, 'Support': 250, 'Tank': 250}}**

Comment: give an example please

Comment: I think it’d be useful to add the nested dictionary in question.

Comment: The first part of the code where I get the data for the dictionary is working this is the second part where a get the two name-keys(first_player and second player) which nested key represent the skill of the player and have to compared.

Comment: @AtanasDinkov What should be the result from `{'Peter': {'Adc': 400}, 'Bush': {'Tank': 150}, 'Frank': {'Mid': 200, 'Support': 250, 'Tank': 250}}` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely if the code is right it should be:

Comment: @AndrejKesely {'Peter': {'Adc': 400}, 'Frank': {'Mid': 200, 'Support': 250, 'Tank': 250}}     -> 'Bush': {'Tank': 150} will be removed completely since has a single key-value pair. If there was something like -> {'Peter': {'Adc': 400}, 'Bush': {'Tank': 150, 'Run': 200}, 'Frank': {'Mid': 200, 'Support': 250, 'Tank': 250}} the result in this case would be -> {'Peter': {'Adc': 400}, 'Bush': {'Run': 200}, 'Frank': {'Mid': 200, 'Support': 250, 'Tank': 250} since 'Mid' 'Thank  has bigger value 250

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose that your dictionnary is in the form that I'm writing here.
In that case, the following code should work

```py
dict = { 'alice' : {'key1' : 1, 'key2' : 2},'bob' : {'key2' : 0.1, 'key3' : 5}, 'carol' : {'key4' : 1}}

#Get the list of all keys, using set.union
listOfKeys = set.union(*[ set(dict[d].keys()) for d in dict ])

print(listOfKeys)
#{'key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4'}

#Get, for each key, a dict of every name who has the key
for k in listOfKeys : 
    namesWithKey = { name : dict[name][k] for name in dict for nameKey in dict[name] if k in nameKey}
    print(k,namesWithKey)
# key3 {'bob': 'key3'}
# key1 {'alice': 'key1'}
# key2 {'alice': 'key2', 'bob': 'key2'}
# key4 {'carol': 'key4'}
    
    #Remove the smallest one
    if len(namesWithKey) > 1 : 
        minName =  min(namesWithKey,key=namesWithKey.get)
        del dict[minName][k]

print(dict)
# {'alice': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}, 'bob': {'key3': 5}, 'carol': {'key4': 1}}
```

Here, we have an arbitrary number of keys and names, and only the intersection get removed, see key 2 that both Alice and Bob have.

Is that the question ?

Comment: This might work. The output seams right. I will we test it in the code. Thank you!

Comment: Is the output correct ? A feedback would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```py
dct = {
    "Peter": {"Adc": 400},
    "Bush": {"Tank": 150},
    "Frank": {"Mid": 200, "Support": 250, "Tank": 250},
}


def compare(dct, key1, key2):
    item1 = dct.pop(key1) if key1 in dct else {}
    item2 = dct.pop(key2) if key2 in dct else {}

    for k in item1.keys() & item2.keys():
        if item1[k] > item2[k]:
            item2.pop(k)
        elif item1[k] < item2[k]:
            item1.pop(k)

    if item1:
        dct[key1] = item1

    if item2:
        dct[key2] = item2


compare(dct, "Bush", "Frank")
print(dct)
```

Prints:

```py
{"Peter": {"Adc": 400}, "Frank": {"Mid": 200, "Support": 250, "Tank": 250}}
```

Comment: Yes the output is correct but by the time we process the dictionary we don't have info for the data inside the dictionary. We don't now the value of N we just receive two names which are two outer keys we have to compare the values of the inner keys which are same by name. In our case 'Bush': {'Thank': 150} and 'Frank': {'Thank': 250}. So we receive only Bush and Frank as a input to compare. The name may not be even valid. But if it is valid we have to perform the operation.

Comment: Hi @Andrej! I implement your code and it is working. Why did you use bit wise &? I tried with logical end and it is not working. I'm still new in this mater so could explain me briefly the idea behind the 'for loop' with '&'. Is this the way to take both items into account every time?

Comment: @AtanasDinkov Look at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). Basically, `for k in item1.keys() & item2.keys()` means that I want to iterate over common keys in `item1` and `item2` dictionaries.

Comment: @Andrei Kesely One more :) How this operator avoid going in this error: "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" which happens if we are using "and"

Comment: @AtanasDinkov Because `item1.keys() & item2.keys()` creates a new object (`set`) and thus we can then freely modify item1 or item2.

Comment: Now is clear, but how you learn this kind stuff? I try to use all available info before I start asking questions, but this looks quite specific at least to me . Where I can find this kind of info I mean other then stackoverflow :). Thank you one more time for your help